# Show a model object in Spring MVC with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

First of all, I defined a simple POJO as follows:

```
public class MyDesc {

    private String desc;

    public MyDesc(String desc) {
        setDesc(desc);
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

}
```

Then, I passed an instance of `MyDesc` as **Spring MVC** *Model* object:

```
@Bean
public MyDesc myDesc() {
    return new MyDesc("Holla!");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("my-desc", myDesc());
    return "pages/home";
}
```

Now, I'd like to show the content into an HTML page by using **Thymeleaf** as *Template Engine*.

```
<div th:text="${my-desc.desc}">Desc placeholder</div>
```

But an error occurs at runtime:

```
Property or field 'desc' cannot be found on null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly because `-` is a valid arithmetic expression for thymeleaf. So here both `my` and `desc` may be getting considered as variables which they are not. Try changing your model variable to `myDesc` and it should work.

There is a broader problem however, you have marked your `myDesc` method as `@Bean`, this does not appear necessary here, any reason to do it?

Comment: It the real case, it's marked as bean into another class.

Comment: Oh, okay, so this bean is injected into the controller and not being used as a method call then I am assuming right, if so it is good. I thought earlier that you are actually calling the `myDesc` method which is not the right way for Java Configuration using Spring.